# Greatest Common Divisor in a ring definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm

We were given this defintion in our Algebra $2$ course:

> **Definition** $4.1$: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $a, b\in R$. An element $d \in R$ is 
>   called a greatest common divisor, $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b)$, of $a$ and $b$ if:
>   • $d$ divides both $a$ and $b$ $($i.e., $\exists x$, $y \in R$ such that $a = dx$, $b = dy$$)$,
>   • If $e \in R$ divides both $a$ and $b$, then $e$ divides $d$.

I don't really understand how the second point could work with say the integers, for example $\operatorname{gcd}(10,12)$, if you pick $2$ to be the first $\operatorname{gcd}$, then for $e=1$ you have that it does divide both $10$ and $12$, and it does divide $2$. But then $2$ doesn't divide $1$ so $2$ is no longer a gcd according to this surely?

Comment: So then $\gcd(10, 12) \ne 1$.  That seems fine to me!

Comment: It's not $2$ which has to divide $1$, according to this definition,  but the reverse.

Comment: Surely they'd both have to divide each other?

Comment: Equivalently, $\, c\mid a,b \iff c\mid \gcd(a,b).\ $ This means the gcd is "greatest" w.r.t. divisibility partial order.

Comment: In your example $ d\mid 10,12\iff d\mid 2\ $ so $\,\gcd(10,12) = 2\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque Why we use commutative ring to define GCD?